# UIKitCore layoutGuides deadlock

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, nslayoutconstraint, uipresentationcontroller

I am creating a popup menu. It has a `UIPresentationController` that calculates `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView` based on presented view controller's view size **before** showing it.

- Presented view controllers consist of the fixed height outer (navigation) view controller embedding some dynamic height inner (content) view controller;
- Inner view controllers, under the hood, have `UIStackView` wrapped in a `UIScrollView`;
- Before calculating size of inner view controller I am calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on it.

The problem occurred only on devices with the notch (I blame safeAreaLayout) and only with a UIStackView-based inner view controllers. When `layoutIfNeeded()` called on presented controller (e.x. when display orientation change, content size change, or presented second time) UIKitCore goes into an infinite loop calling `-[UIView layoutGuides]`. It doesn't crash the app, but use 100% of the main thread and freezes the UI(sometimes whole phone to the point you need make a hard reset), consuming about 10Mb of memory every second.

I was able to fix it by adding **1 extra point** to a calculated height of the `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView`. This sounds like an awful fix, so I am trying to better understand the problem.

I would be glad if someone with a deep understanding of UIKit could point me to a better strategy on how to debug/investigate the issue.

---

**UPDATE**

Seems like `UIScrollView` having hard time positioning content due to a safeArea. UIKitCore keeps repeating those 5 lines:

```
- [UIScrollView _layoutGuideOfType:createIfNecessary:]
- [NSISEngine(_UILayoutEngineStatistics)_UIKitPerformPendingChangeNotifications]
- [UIView layoutGuides]
- [_UIScrollViewScrollIndicator _layoutFillViewAnimated:]
- [UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:onBehalfOfLayoutGuide:]
```

I also have

```
runtime: Layout Issues: Scrollable content size is ambiguous for UIScrollView.
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that was the case with your code, but I found a similar problem when I had a view added to the scroll view that was from a child view controller of the one hosting the scroll view, and the issue happened because I forgot to add the child view controller (addChild() and then didMove(...))

Comment: What do you mean by "UIKitCore".  There is NO framework component in apple named "UIKitCore".  You must mean UIKit.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix my issue by specifically attaching UIScrollView to the bottom of safeAreaLayoutGuide.

```
var bottomConstraint = formView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    bottomConstraint = formView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
}
```

Comment: You are a god among humanity. Thank you!